# What order does this bug belong to?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I caught this insect in my house.
It has 6 legs, long antennae, 2 pairs of wings and is dark brown.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your geographic location. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Order Coleoptera, Family Cerambycidae.

Comment: You could confirm the family ID by looking at the eyes. They are kidney-bean shaped, with the base of the antennae inserting into the concavity.